# Transform my Code to redirect to User Profile

Tags: php

This code

```
$threadOut .= "<tr><td>".$uData->user_login."<br/><small>".$this->formatDate($post->date)."</small><br/><a href='".get_author_posts_url( $u->ID )."'>".__("My Profile")."</a>".get_avatar($post->from_user, 60)."</td>";
```

echos some data and a link (My Profile) wich redirects to:

http: // mydomain.com / user/

This code filters the users data (username):

```
.$u->user_login.
```

I dont get it :( Can anyone help me to transform the first code - so it redirects my "My Profile" Link to:

http:  //  mydomain.com /user /username

All other parts should stay the same. Thank you so much - best regards

Comment: Add more php code for better realization of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$threadOut .= "<tr><td>".$uData->user_login."<br/><small>".$this->formatDate($post->date)."</small><br/><a href='".get_author_posts_url( $u->ID ).$uData->user_login."'>".__("My Profile")."</a>".get_avatar($post->from_user, 60)."</td>";
```

Added `.$uData->user_login.` to the link

Comment: Works but the / is to much! Can you edit your answer please. Thank you so much for this fast response ;) BEST

Comment: Where it says `.$uData->user_login."'>"` change to `.$uData->user_login."' target='_blank'>"`

Comment: YESsssss works great... Sorry for my stupid Q but now i have one more idea :) can i get the same url to the Profil if someone clicks on the avatar or should i ask a new Q for that...

Comment: You should be able to apply the same pattern of changes to the avatar link. Try and figure out what changes I made and you can make them yourself in the future!